# Changing and retaining specific a-tag background color once clicked in PHP

Tags: php, css

I've got a a-tag dynamically populated which extracts data from a database and multiplies to the number of records existing. So this to be looked at more like an item in a list.

```
echo "<a class='Keylist ".$wecb_color."' id='myIDhere' href='index.php?idd=".$record['categoryid']."'><div>".$record['descriptor']."</div></a>";
```

I'm trying to keep one of the a-tags background set on a different color when a user clicks. Behavior I'm trying to achieve is when a user scrolls and clicked on one link, that a-tag to remain selected depicting a different background color.

I've written snippet trying to do that.

```
$wecb_color ='';
if(isset($_GET['idd'])){
    $_SESSION['link'] = $_GET['idd'];
    echo "<br><br><br><br><br>".$_SESSION['link'];

    if($_GET['idd'] == $_SESSION ['link']) {
    $wecb_color = 'changetogreen';
    }

}
```

The issue is this makes all the a-tag's which are generated having a background color changed to green instead the one that user clicks.

Hard coded CSS script reads as :- `.changetogreen{background-color: green;}`

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383171/changing-the-background-color-of-a-link-after-being-clicked) might help! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It'd change the background color of all links because you're changing the whole class style. 
Try this:

```
echo "<a class='"Keylist " style=" '.$wecb_style.' ;" id='myIDhere' href='index.php?idd=".$record['categoryid']."'><div>".$record['descriptor']."</div></a>";
```

So you can change the style of particular tag.
And PHP would be:

```
$wecb_style ='';
if(isset($_GET['idd'])){
    $_SESSION['link'] = $_GET['idd'];
    echo "<br><br><br><br><br>".$_SESSION['link'];

    if($_GET['idd'] == $_SESSION ['link']) {
    $wecb_style = 'background: green';
    }

}
```